# Querying entities distinct by property in BreezeJs

Tags: javascript, entity-framework, breeze

I'm looking for a way to compose a Breeze entity query that allows me to take the top 10 entities that are distinguished by a particular property.

This LINQ snippet describes roughly what I'm trying to do:

```
repo.Foos()
    .GroupBy(foo => foo.Bar)
    .OrderByDescending(fooGroup => fooGroup.Max(foo => foo.Baz))
    .Select(fooGroup => fooGroup.First())
    .Take(10);
```

I wish to take the top 10 Foo entities that have distinct Bar properties ordered by some third Baz property. Is there anyway to achieve this in Breeze? I'm aware there's no `groupBy` functionality, but perhaps there's an alternative route.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an endpoint on your server that performs the query you want:

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Foo> TopTenFoos()
{
    return repo.Foos()
        .GroupBy(foo => foo.Bar)
        .OrderByDescending(fooGroup => fooGroup.Max(foo => foo.Baz))
        .Select(fooGroup => fooGroup.First())
}
```

Then call it with breeze, e.g.

```
breeze.EntityQuery.from('TopTenFoos').toType('Foo').take(10);
```

Comment: I'm already doing this. I was just curious to see if there was a way to construct the query clientside.